# How to correctly set the minimum iOS version for my app?

Tags: ios, ios4, ios-3.x

I am developed one application in ios 4.2. I try to test that application in iphone 3g. In that process error will occur like

> "The Info.plist for application at
>   /Users/gvrao/Desktop/BabyCryApp/build/Debug-iphoneos/BabyCryApp.app
>   specifies a minimum OS version of 4.2,
>   which is too high to be installed on
>   iphone 3g"

And change the version in iphone development target to 3.1.3. But it was not working. Please tell me how to solve this problem.

Comment: From the command line, use `-mios-version-min=3.1`.

Comment: This feels churlish to close this question imho, it's clear what the question is and that the asker of the question's first language is not English. In these situations I would hope rather than close the question the person thinking about doing so would just clean up the question instead.  I found both the question and the answer useful fyi.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You need to set the Deployment target in the build settings to the minimum iOS version you require.

A general guideline is to set:

- Base SDK to latest
- deployment target to the minimum version you support.

Also - check your Info.plist file for the `MinimumOSVersion` key.

Comment: And what is in your Info.plist file?

Comment: Please don't use **MinimumOSVersion** in the Info.plist file. As you can find in the [Information Property List Key Reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/LaunchServicesKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009250-SW18): MinimumOSVersion (String - iOS). When you build an iOS app, Xcode uses the iOS Deployment Target setting of the project to set the value for the MinimumOSVersion key. **Do not specify** this key yourself in the Info.plist file; it is a system-written key

Comment: @FabianoFrancesconi  I didn't say write to it, I said check it. :)

Comment: Hi @FabianoFrancesconi I am not using XCode to build my app(i am using phonegap build with javascript, html and css) so therefore im not sure how the minimum version will be set.. My app is only compatible with ios8.0 upwards. I know I can set plist values in my config.xml file... Do you advise I use LSMinimumSystemVersion for this?

Comment: @Sarah yes go for something similar to `<gap:config-file platform="ios" parent="LSMinimumSystemVersion">
    <string>7.0</string>
</gap:config-file>`

Comment: @FabianoFrancesconi, According to documentation, LSMinimumSystemVersion is only for macOS. But when I manually add that deployment setting, it still translates to LSMinimumSystemVersion(when info.plist is viewed as xml)... Despite it being an iOS project.

Answer (score 0):

Do you get build errors when you try to build for version 3.1.3 in xcode.

iOS4 SDK has a lot of features that possibly are not featured in older versions of the the firmware.

Comment: The Info.plist for application at /Users/gvrao/Desktop/BabyCryApp/build/Debug-iphoneos/BabyCryApp.app specifies a minimum OS version of 4.2, which is too high to be installed on iphone 3g